# Rails - Include association in json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I got 2 Tables/Models: Paths and Questions. Each question belongs to a path

My question.rb:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :path
end
```

My path.rb

```
class Path < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions
end
```

Everything works fine like

```
p = Path.last
Path.questions
```

returns everything I need but I'm returning a json response like this:

```
@path = Path.find_by_id(params[:id])
render :status=>200, :json => {:status => "success", :path => @path, :message => "Showing path"}
```

That answer doesn't include the questions for the path of course. What do I have to change to include all questions belonging to that path? I know I could just add :path_questions => @path.questions but is there no way to include the questions without a new return variable? I hope it's clear what I mean.

Comment: it is well documented in https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Answer (score 11):

I do it like that in a Rails 5 API app:

```
BooksController

def index
  @books = Book.limit(params[:limit])
  render json: @books, include: ['author'], meta: { total: Book.count }
end
```

In the above situation, a **Book** `belongs_to` **Author**.

Comment: Worked for me. Your answer is simple and clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite hacky, but should work:

```
:path => @path.as_json.merge(:questions => @path.questions.as_json)
```

Eventually you can override as_json inside your model:

```
def as_json(options={})
  includes = [*options.delete(:include)]
  hash = super(options)
  includes.each do |association|
    hash[self.class.name.underscore][association.to_s] = self.send(association).as_json
  end
  hash
end
```

And then just call: `:path => @path.as_json(:include => :questions)`

Note it will also add `:include` option to to_json method.